# How should I obtain the covariance matrix for the fit parameters calculated by numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit?

Tags: python, numpy

In the past I have used the numpy.polyfit function for least-squares fitting to a straight line in a first-year programming course for physics students. However, the NumPy documentation now recommends using numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit instead as this newer Polynomial library is more stable numerically. However, the newer function does not have the `cov` parameter to calculate the covariance matrix as well as the best-fit values for the parameters.

Is there a way to get this information from numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit, or is there another NumPy function that can be used instead?

This can be done using scipy.optimize.curve_fit, but I would like to avoid the additional complexity for now as most of our students are new to programming.